# How to run multiple SOAP requests from Excel spreadsheet in SoapUI?

Tags: excel, soap, soapui

I have a spreadsheet where each row contains a SOAP request, concatenated from the data in that row. So cell G2 is a SOAP request, cell G3 is a different SOAP request, cell G4 is another SOAP request and so on. I've looked to see what is the best method for transferring those 100+ SOAP requests into SoapUI (free version) and running them all in one batch. I've not found anything that gives me the full working solution yet. Could someone suggest the best method please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't tell you how to do it, but I can tell you how I did it. Concatenating XML in Excel is messy and error-prone, especialy if you have less-technical people writing the test cases. I asked for the data (parameters) in Excel.

I wrote a Groovy script that gets the data (there's a nice [script](https://technipelago.se/content/technipelago/blog/44) that abstracts it for you), and for each test case, saved the values as properties:

```
new ExcelBuilder("data/MyRegressionSheetV1.2.xls").eachLine([labels:true]) { row ->
    Map payLoad = [:]
    if (cell(0)) {
        payLoad['MyName'] = cell(0)
        payLoad['MySurname'] = cell(1)
        //and so on
        payLoad['ExpectedResult'] = cell(12)
    
        testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("Name", payLoad['MyName'])
        testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.setPropertyValue("Surname", payLoad['MySurname'])
        //and so on

        def MyScenario = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["SOAP Request1"].run( null, true )
```

then made the SOAP requests with parameterised values:

```
        <parm:Name>${#Project#Name}</parm:Name>
        <parm:Surname>${#Project#Surname}</parm:Surname>
        //and so on
```

While in the loop, you can get the response values and if you have expected results, you can compare them programmatically:

```
        def responseSOAP = context.expand('${SOAP Request1#Response}')
        def responseSection = responseSOAP =~ /requestAnswer>(.*)<\/requestAnswer/
        def response = responseSection[0][1]
        if (response.equals(payLoad['ExpectedResult'])) {
            testResult = 'Pass'
        }
    }
```

Opensource SoapUI is very capable, and Groovy is a very cool programming language. A lot is possible once you get your head around how they work together.

EDIT:
If you want to replace the entire request, you can access it with the XmlHolder:

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
//this gets a handle on the current request XML
def oldHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( 'SOAP Request1#Request' )
//your String XML from the spreadsheet must be parsed into XML
def newHolder = new XmlSlurper().parseText(MyXMLFromSheetAsString)
//replace
context.requestContent = newHolder.xml
```

Comment: Hi @ou_ryperd, thank you very much for your answer! There are quite a few bits that I'm not sure about, but I will give this a try today and come back with an update. I completely agree with the comment about the reliability of the concat, but I have faith in the content of that field as I've tested a sample of those SOAP requests individually and they're good. So ideally I'd like to just to grab that one cell per row for each SOAP request. I think I can work that out from your suggestion, but I'll try it and let you know. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: @PhilNeale I updated my answer with how to do that. I haven't tested it but it should be close enough.

Comment: Hi @ou_ryperd, thank you very much! I've muddled through this and seem to have got what I needed, so I'm very grateful to you for your answer. Best wishes and thanks!